# Special characters turning up in tm package/ qdap output

Tags: r, special-characters, tm, qdap

I am trying to create a term-document matrix in R using the following dataset

```
  EmailSubject
Buy the stunning new phone
The game changer is here.
Experience a phone ahead of its time.
Thank You Chennai
Limited Period offer
Valentines day special
Buy a phone at 10000 and get a new sim free
Limited Period offer
Valentines day special
Buy a phone at 10000 and get a new sim free
Buy the stunning new phone
The game changer is here.
Experience a phone ahead of its time.
Thank You Chennai
Limited Period offer
Valentines day special
Buy a phone at 10000 and get a new sim free
Thank You Chennai
Limited Period offer
 Valentines day special
 Buy a phone at 10000 and get a new sim free
Buy a phone at 10000 and get a new sim free
Buy the stunning new phone
The game changer is here.
```

Experience a phone ahead of its time.
   Thank You Chennai
    Limited Period offer

I have used qdap and freq_terms. The following is the expected output

```
  freq_terms(DF)


     Expected Output    Frequency
      Buy               4
      Get               5
       a                7
      thank             12
     Stunning            6
         The             7
         New             10
       Valentines        4
        phone            7
```

The following special characters appear constantly and render the data unsuitable.

```
           valentinea€™s, a€™s instead of valentines, as. I have tried the same with tm package also.
```

I have used gsub to replace these characters but it's not very effective. Can someone suggest a way?

Comment: Sounds like an `?Encoding` issue